# RegEx to verify this pattern

Tags: php

I have a string in this format `D9D04D51-EF4A-4745-492A-D1341C3F0636`.

Is it possible to have a Regular Expression to check for 4 hyphens and a character length of 36?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

online regex test: https://regex101.com/r/BtTdfI/1/

```
$regex = '/^[A-Z0-9]{8}[-][A-Z0-9]{4}[-][A-Z0-9]{4}[-][A-Z0-9]{4}[-][A-Z0-9]{12}$/gi';
```

example:

```
D9D04D51-EF4A-4745-492A-D1341C3F0636 => true

D9D04D51-EF4A-4745-492A-D1341C3F06361 => false
```

Comment: `$regex = /^[A-Z0-9]+-[A-Z0-9]+-[A-Z0-9]+-[A-Z0-9]+$/g`

Example : https://regex101.com/r/IMJa1J/1/